# Write data to json file?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an app using jqm+phonegap. I want to store the selected options from two selection menus in a json file locally. I know how to read data (using getJSON) from json file but i dot know how to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap exposes a `file` api: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File

I haven't tried to use PhoneGap's `file` api it for several months but Lawnchair is quite a bit easier to use (just my opinion).

You could also check-out [Lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/), it makes storing data on a device easy.

Comment: i am already using json to store data and i am accessing that data in my app. Actually my real problem is: I have two selectmenus (with 5 options each and both are linked for example, for option A in first selection there are 3 options in second menu and for option B there are 2 options and so on..) on a single page.

I want to create another selectmenu on the same page whose options should be the (last 10) recent combinations of options selected from the other two selectmenus.

Comment: @G.S JavaScript natively does not have any methods for writing to a filesystem. So you'll need to rely on HTML5 web-storage or PhoneGap's API. There are examples in the links I posted for both of those methods.

Comment: $("#selectShade").change(checkShade);  
                
  function checkShade(){ 
  localStorage.setItem("title","My best  App");
         localStorage.setItem("author", "john");}
   This is not working when the checkShade() is fired.When i try to select some option from my menu #selectShade, selectmen hangs and i am not able to select the option. If i remove these two lines (localStorage) from checkShade() and write alert("hi"); then it works.help?

Comment: sorry. it's working. Actually i was not running it in browser.